# Company decides standard language for all development, or coder can pick their own standard...so that is the standard? What is the norm?

Tags: programming-languages

Our company is moving from IBM mainframe environment and coding, to an OO environment. Is it possible...or is it correct/plausable to NOT have any standard whatsoever with regard to the server side language of the OO environment we move to? Is it normal to say "Dave works in PHP" so all things he does will be in "PHP"...and we'll hire Liz who has Python..that will work too.  Dave works on a financial application in PHP, will Liz does time cards in Python.  OR would it be better to say.."Company ABC programming standard is Python..." Dave has to learn Python, and Liz is ready to rock and roll with the company. I'm just trying to know what an OO environment looks like with regard to standardized language or free do what  works best for the situation/coder environment.

Comment: What's an "OO" environment?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Object Oriented...maybe using wrong or older term. What is the term for the stacked environment?

Comment: We know what "OO" stands for, but what kind of environment do you associate with that term, as you are talking about it as opposed to an "IBM mainframe environment"? Is an "IBM mainframe environment" not programmable with object oriented means? AFAIK IBM made a big fuzz about Java on OS/390.

Answer (score 7):

Typically, companies standardize on a single language for a variety of reasons (tool support, talent availability, interoperability, etc). I've worked for some companies that used multiple languages, but they were the exception. Having individuals pick their own technologies is usually a recipe for disaster. When the PHP guy leaves, if nobody else knows PHP then who takes over his code? And do you keep it in PHP or will you wind up rewriting it in the "new guy"'s language of choice?

Comment: Not to mention what happens if there are three people who suddenly need to work on the same project, with the same files, and only one of them knows PHP because the others were hired when they could choose whatever they wanted to. Then they start complaining "Why does Liz get to *choose* to work in Python, but I *have* to work in PHP because Dave made that decision 2 years ago?"

Comment: But when the company picks a language coders don't like...then what happens? Company picks Ruby, upsets Dave and Liz...they walk? Company picks "insert older technology here"...Dave and Liz know it but say it's old...they walk...

Comment: @VSW ...and then company replaces Dave and Liz with Ruby programmers that hopefully aren't *prima donnas*.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using multiple languages as long as there is enough organizational knowledge not only on the language, but the frameworks and applications built using the language. In my experience, homogenous environments tend to be inflexible. Use the right tool for the job, even if that means picking up a new tool.

Comment: @VSW: Ideally, there would be discussion among all the employees before the pick something to standardize on. Their input should be taken and considered when deciding on what to standardize on (although there should be other inputs to this process). And yes, if someone would really prefer to give up their job than learn a new language, I guess that's what they'd have to do. Most mature programmers I know are willing to learn new languages if necessary, and some even look forward to it. People who refuse to learn seem immature, and will eventually get left behind.

Comment: @Snowman: I just waited for that "right tool for the job" phrase - in language discussions, someone will always throw this buzzword in. It is not completely wrong, but fact is, for at least 90% of all programming tasks within a company you can choose any of the popular multi-purpose languages, and assumed the programmer has a modest level of knowledge in that language, he can solve the task with it.

Comment: @DocBrown I would agree that e.g. if you work for a company that produces web apps, standardizing on .NET or Java would be irrelevant for those reasons. But I have worked places that standardized so rigidly that even custom command-line tools had to be written in the same language as the web apps. No shell/batch scripting. We had to make an argument that only SQL could be used to query a relational database. That gig did not last long...

Comment: @Snowman: I guess we are thinking in the same direction. For example, if you need some custom commmand line tools, it will absolutely make sense to use some kind of scripting language. But it is typically unnecessary to write one tool in Perl, one in Ruby, one in Python, one in awk/bash, and one in VBScript. But that can easily happen when every dev of your team is 100% free to choose what he thinks is "the right tool for the job".

Comment: +1. The main exception is usually consulting companies. They will often have a broader range of skillsets than in-house dev teams, or small software product houses

Comment: @VSW: That happens. I was at a company that was a Java shop and they entered into a partnership deal with Microsoft so we all switched to .NET. Some people left rather than make the switch, claiming that if the project went south they'd be stuck as entry-level .NET developers with no current Java experience. I didn't agree, but I didn't try to talk them out of it either.

Answer (score 5):

It should be pretty obvious that if you have two or more persons working on the same program, they need to use the same language, or at least the same (small) set of languages. So when there is is only one team or department in the company who does software development, they will typically not make their lifes harder by unnecessarily chosing a new language for every new program they have to develop.

The real world situation looks often like this: in lots of companies of reasonable size, you will find different, independent teams or departments, which chose they toolset some time ago for a specific programming task. And if the teams are working independently, the chances are high they make different decisions about the programming language. The bigger the company, the more likely this will happen.

After a while, most companies tend to change their structure, for example one department will be closed or cut down to half of the people, or the programming tasks are "outsourced" to a different department, which can easily lead to a situation where another department has to take over some existing software packages for maintenance. Or two former independent departments have to work together on a common software project. This will quickly leave you in a situation where one team has to manage different programs in different languages. And that is IMHO the "norm" for lots of companies I have seen before - not because "it works best", but because "that's the way it works".